# Круговое расположение элементов Android

Tags: android, вёрстка, view

Как можно расположить элементы подобным образм[image: введите сюда описание изображения]?

Comment: https://github.com/oguzbilgener/CircularFloatingActionMenu начните отсюда, а там уже ясно что гуглить и куда рыть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, причем использую принципы Material Design взяв за основной элемент - центральный icon с крестиком.

**RelativeLayout** хорошо подойдет, расположите второстепенные элементы относительно главного, останется только выставить нужные отступы. Не придется даже использовать дополнительные ViewGroup.

Comment: я думаю нужно еще и анимации

Comment: я думаю с анимацией тоже не должно быть проблем

Comment: @KirillStoianov я как бы не кэп, но если вопрос задан, то проблемы уже есть

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, так я и сделал, просто подумал, что может есть еще какой-нибудь вариант реализации)

Answer (score 1):

Вот примерная реализация предложенная в ответе выше:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@color/blue_grey_500">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_top"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_top"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left_bottom"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/center"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right_bottom"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/center"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]